# Create a select statement that turn one column into Mutliple columns using Char Index or something similar

Tags: sql, sql-server

1) Question 1 : Splitting after every 6th digit, basically I need to split my columns after every 5th digit so that 123456 creates to columns , ones with 12345 and a second with 6, I have tried using the code below with no result. there are no spaces or symbols , just digits.

`substring(COA.UserCode2,5,charindex('',COA.UserCode2)) as Account`,
 `substring(COA.UserCode2,6,charindex('',COA.UserCode2)) as Project`

2) Question 2: Splitting after every * , I can get the first one below to work (Fund)  but my cost center and Source don't work basically if I have a string like 1234*34*500, I need the column for fund to have 1234 ( This I got already) , my Cost center to say 34 and my source to say 500

`substring(COA.UserCode3, 1,charindex('*',COA.UserCode3)) as Fund,`
 `substring(COA.UserCode3, 3,charindex('*',COA.UserCode3)+1) as CostCenter,`
  `substring(COA.UserCode3, 1,charindex('*',COA.UserCode3)) as Source`

Comment: which DMBS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing what DBMS you use (if it has specific SQL extensions etcetera) or how the data looks here is at least some suggestions:

1) If the data is fixed in size (always 6 chars long) you could do this:

```
SUBSTRING(UserCode2,1,5) as Account, SUBSTRING(UserCode2,6,1) as Project
```

2) For the second question you could do any of these:

If the data is fixed:

```
SUBSTRING(UserCode3,1,4) as Fund, 
SUBSTRING(UserCode3,6,2) as CostCenter, 
SUBSTRING(UserCode3,9,2) as Source
```

Or if the data is variable and you have to split on the * chars:

```
SUBSTRING(UserCode3,1,CHARINDEX('*',UserCode3,1)-1) as Fund,
SUBSTRING(UserCode3,CHARINDEX('*',UserCode3,1)+1,CHARINDEX('*',UserCode3,CHARINDEX('*',UserCode3,1)+1) - CHARINDEX('*',UserCode3,1)-1) as CostCenter,
RIGHT(UserCode3,3) as Source
```

Doing this many CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING functions would probably be bad for performance, but without knowing more about the data it's a bit difficult making informed suggestions.

Comment: im using Microsoft sql . the length wont always be 6 , sometime it can be 2 sometime 15 , I was wondering if there is a way to always breat it apart after the 5th digit regardless of how manu digits it was.

Comment: JPW,Thank you very much for the Help. Im creating an SSRS report and there wont be more than a couple hundred records at a time. for number 2 you have ansered it perfectly It works like a charm , its not always the same length but I always have to break at the *.

Comment: If you always want to break the data apart after the 5th character and return two strings (the first 5 chars long and the second whatever is left) you could use this:

**SUBSTRING(UserCode2,1,5) as Account, SUBSTRING(UserCode2,6,LEN(UserCode2)) as Project**